# how to send response from consumer to producer to the particular request using Spring AMQP?

Tags: spring-amqp

we have one problem statement in our application where we are getting null response at the producer end.

1> Producer will produce message (REQUEST_QUEUE) and it will wait for the response.

```
Object receivedData = amqpTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("IKEY123456");
System.out.println("RESPONSE DATA: " + receivedData);
```

2> At consumer end it will consume message and

```
Class TestConsumer {
    AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate;

    public void methodA(){
        String msg = (String)amqpTemplate.receiveAndConvert()
        process(msg);
    }

    public void process(String msg){
        // ... process something on that message
        Object resData = service.makeChanges(msg);

        // I want to send 'resData" object back to the producer
        amqpTemplate.convertAndSend(resData);
    }
}
```

Response at producer end is null. "RESPONSE DATA: null"

Can anyone tell me how to send response back to producer and how to achieve correct response received to the request which we send.

Answer (score 2):

The main trick in request/reply patter in the messaging is `correlation`.

By default the `RabbitTemplate` creates  a new temporary **queue** for each reply and populate it to the `replyTo` message property.

You main issue on the consumer side that you don't send a reply to that `replyTo` queue from the request.

Would be better and straightforward, if you will use the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to receive a request from the `requestQueue`. In this case you can use your `TestConsumer` as POJO listener and wrap it to the `MessageListenerAdapter`. The last one takes care about `replyTo` and `correlationId`:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer serviceListenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(requestQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new PojoListener()));
    return container;
}

public class PojoListener {

    public String handleMessage(String foo) {
        return foo.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

It is the simplest way to correlate.

Another case is around the fixed `replyQueue`, `replyListener` and, of course, the `correlationId` for the request and reply. There is need more configurations on producer side, but the consumer part is the same - `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with `MessageListenerAdapter`.

You can get more info from the [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#request-reply)